# Where is it stated the CastRemoteDisplay api is deprecated and is it correct there are no alternatives?

Tags: casting, deprecated, google-cast

In different answers provided this year it has been stated that CastRemoteDisplay was deprecated and no alternatives were presently available. 
It is stated that the CastRemoteDisplayAPI interface is deprecated but CastRemoteDisplay class not and in the doc for both CastRemoteDisplay (class) and CastRemoteDisplayAPI (interface) it is stated that CastRemoteDisplayLocalServices provide an easier solution. Why is the CastRemoteDisplayLocalService class not considered an alternative?